# Can an SSDT project build use multiple cores?

Tags: msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I have a very large SSDT project in VS 2013 that takes about 30 mins to build.  When building it's obvious that msbuild.exe is only using one core.

Is there a way to get an SSDT project to utilise all cores on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
Normal things to try are:

- Disable treat t-SQL warnings as errors
- Split the project into multiple ones and use dacpac references on parts of it that don't change
- There is an option that changes how the models are generated from disk to memory, if your hitting the 2gb vs limit so doing lots of gc'ing you could try it (DACFX_MODEL_STORAGE_TYPE):

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/749108/msbuild-fails-randomly-with-version-store-out-of-memory-cleanup-already-attempted-errors-msb4018

Ed

Comment: Thanks Ed.  I was pretty sure the answer was no, but thought I'd check.  I've already turned off "Treat T-SQL Warnings as errors".  This project also suffers from a massive list of warnings, and I found suppressing these speeds up the build.  Also ensured static code analysis is off.  I guess we just need a beefier VM platform